# Gnome 3.16: Disable color manager

Tags: gnome, colors, manjaro

First, I have Manjaro with Gnome 3.16.

By default, my screen looks unreadable, so I put in `~/.profile` `xcalib -gammacor 1.3 -alter` in order to fix it every time I log in.

It seems to work, but that adjustment is reverted in one or two seconds. If I apply that command manually after, the change is not reverted.

So, I believe that Gnome manages the screen color in some way, but I don't know how to disable it (I have tried to do this in 'Color' configuration, with no result). Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved it! You should have installed dconf editor

Then, go to `org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > color` and uncheck `active`field.